# Java equivalent of Objective-C instancetype?

Tags: java, objective-c, types

In Objective-C, [`instancetype`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html) can be used as the return type of methods that return an instance of the class they are called on (or a subclass of that class).

What is the equivalent of `instancetype` in Java?

Comment: As far as I can tell, Java does not have any equivalent functionality.

Comment: Java constructors have no declared return type like in Objective-C so there is no need for anything like `instancetype` in Java.

Answer (score 4):

The closest to thing is to use generics

```
interface Base<B extends Base<B>> {
    // do something and return this.
    B append(String s);
}

interface SubBase<B extends SubBase<B>> extends Base<SubBase<B>> {
    // append returns a SubBase<B>
}

class MyClass implements SubBase<MyClass> {
    public MyClass append(String s) {
         // do something
         return this;
    }
}
```

It's not so elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean something like this:

```
class Vehicle {
    instancetype doNothing() {return this;}
}
class Car extends Vehicle {}

Car c = new Car().doNothing(); // no compile errors here
```

There is no equivalent.

One workaround that's sometimes used is to pass the type as a generic parameter:

```
class Vehicle<instancetype> {
    instancetype doNothing() {return this;}
}
class Car extends Vehicle<Car> {}

Car c = new Car().doNothing(); // works
```

but then you can't use the type `Vehicle` without getting warnings everywhere (it has to be `Vehicle<?>`).

Comment: @Abdellah well in that case, the equivalent is to just use the class name, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Mmm I see ..  `unless I'm missing something? ` this is my doubt too

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Javaist but likely there is no equivalent, because Java needs it only rarely. (And Objective-C do so, too.)

Please note that in Objective-C you do not need it most of the time, too. This is, because the compiler infers the "real" return type from the receiver, even it is declared `id`. This applies to `-init…`, `+alloc…`, `-new…`:

> To determine whether a method has an inferred related result type, the first word in the camel-case selector (e.g., “init” in “initWithObjects”) is considered, and the method will have a related result type if its return type is compatible with the type of its class and if:
>
> - the first word is “alloc” or “new”, and the method is a class method, or
> - the first word is “autorelease”, “init”, “retain”, or “self”, and the method is an instance method.

In Java this is inferred for the `new` operator, too. The constructors does not have any return type, so it does not need to be inferred.

Up to here: No need for an (explicit) keyword in Java or Objective-C.

In some cases you have additional methods returning a new instance of the receivers class. Cloning/copying is such a case. In Java you have to type cast the result. In Objective-C you can use `instancetype` to make code easier to read. (BTW: `NSObject`'s `-copy` has `id` as return type, not `instancetype`. But again usually this is no problem, because you typically assign the return value to a typed reference.)

So the short conclusion: In both Java and Objective-C the return type can be and is inferred by the compiler for most of the use cases. In rare use cases you have to explicitly cast in Java.